# Eclipse : find/replace regular expression button disappeared

Tags: eclipse

I often use the find/replace in my Eclipse. But for an unknown reason this morning this box "regular expression" disappeared.

[image: Screenshot]

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Find/Replace dialog has been resized and there is not room for the Regular Expression line.

Just drag the bottom of the dialog down to reveal the full dialog.

Comment: Seriously ?! Woah I feel like an idiot now haha... Thx greg :)

Comment: Wow... I upgraded Eclipse versions and my find/replace was "empty." The default view of this window after the upgrade was small enough where nothing was showing, and I was thinking it was a bug. I guess it technically is. This window should have a minimum size.